# Nodejs doesnt recognize async function and reference

Tags: node.js

When i run my project in terminal like this
node index.js

I get a reference error: config not defined

/home/ether/Documents/nodesendeth/index.js:6
const {asset, base, spread, allocation} = config;
^

```
ReferenceError: config is not defined
    at tick (/home/ether/Documents/nodesendeth/index.js:6:47)
    at run (/home/ether/Documents/nodesendeth/index.js:49:3)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ether/Documents/nodesendeth/index.js:52:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1151:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1171:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:71:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

in my code i have assigned the config constant like this:

```
require('dotenv').config;
const ccxt = require('ccxt');
const axios = require('axios');

const tick = async => {
    const {asset, base, spread, allocation} = config;
    const market = `${asset}/${base}`;

    const orders =  binanceClient.fetchOpenOrders(market);
    orders.forEach(async order => {
        await binanceClient.cancelOrder(order.id);
    });
    const results =  Promise.all([
      axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=bitcoin&vs_currencies=usd'),
      axios.get('https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids=tether&vs_currencies=usd')
    ]);
    const marketPrice = results[0].data.bitcoin.usd / results[1].data.tether.usd;

    const sellPrice = marketPrice * (1 + spread);
    const buyPrice = marketPrice  * (1 - spread);
    const balances = binanceClient.fetchBalance();
    const assetBalance = balances.free[asset];
    const baseBalance = balances.free[base];
    const sellVolume = assetBalance * allocation;
    const buyVolume = (baseBalance * allocation) / marketPrice;

    binanceClient.createLimitSellOrder(market, sellVolume, sellPrice);
    binanceClient.createLimitBuyOrder(market, sellVolume, buyPrice);

     console.log(`
        New tick for ${market}...
        Created limit sell order for ${sellVolume}@${sellPrice}
        Create limit buy order for ${buyVolume}@${buyPrice}`)
}

const run = () => {
    const config = {
      asset: 'BTC',
      base: 'USDT',
      allocation: 0.1,
      spread: 0.2,
      tickInterval: 2000
    };
  const binanceClient = new ccxt.binance({
    apiKey: process.env.API_ENV,
    secret: process.env.API_SECRET,
  });

  tick(config, binanceClient);
  setInterval(tick, config.tickInterval, config, binanceClient);
}
run()
```

I also got await errors saying that i need to run them in an sync function which I do.
i have removed the await keyword now but the app should run with the await kewyword because those functions are async.

Why am i getting those errors when i have a config variable aswell as an async function?

I assume that something with my async function doesnt work because it neither recognises the config constant nor the async/await calls

Comment: `const {asset, base, spread, allocation} = config;`  What do you think `config` is in this line?

Comment: Which module do `{asset, base, spread, allocation}` come from?

Comment: i dont know which module you mean

Comment: Are those environment variables that you expect to have be defined in your .env file?

Answer (score 1):

`config` is undefined in your code.

You likely meant to declare it on this line, as follows:

```
const config = require('dotenv').config();
```

...but this is only half of your problem because, furthermore, the object returned by `.config()` puts all the variables in a `parsed` property.

So for example, if your .env looked like this:

```
apple=red
ball=blue
```

...and you just logged `config`, you'd see this:

```
{ parsed: { apple: 'red', ball: 'blue' } }
```

Then you could write:

```
const {apple, ball} = require('dotenv').config().parsed;
console.log(apple, ball);
```

And this would write:

```
red blue
```

In your specific case, if you are expecting `asset`, `base`, `spread`, and `allocation` to be environment variables in your .env file, then you could potentially change the line to say:

```
const {asset, base, spread, allocation} = config.parsed;
```

Comment: ok, this fixed the above error but it still errors out on all my constant, now it is saying i didnt declare binanceClient, when it is declared. and my async/await errors are still here. Am i not making a mistake somewhere else

Comment: I'm guessing a lot here because you haven't fully disclosed what you're trying to do, but based on my guesses I've added more information that will hopefully let you fix things up.